# Best way to develop a level from Top down image using 3dmax

Tags: 3d, models, 3dsmax

I have to create a game level from a top down view of an area. I used a plane converted to an editable poly to do the job. I used edges to create the top view of roads, walkways and parks so that i can extrude/edit them later. 
My problem is the curves in the road look blocky I tried appying mesh smooth modifier on the final model but that interfered with material mapping. Again i tried it on the plane without the extrusions and still the modifier does not work(The roads loose their shape). I know one way to solve the problem is to add more vertices on the curve and transform their location to create a more natural curve but i have a lot of curves so before doing it manually i need to know if there is a tool that refines the curves. Also i need to know if there is a better or proper way of doing the task.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this, depending on what your final result wants to look like, but for the majority they all start with using the line tool - found in the spline section, this tool has the ability to change the control points to bezier, which means you have full control over the curve. You can also adjust the amount of points in the curve between each control point allowing you to make completely smooth curves.

You could draw the entire road (both sides and end caps) with this and apply something like a surface modifier to create a simple flat road.

Or you create a slice of the road's shape, so it includes curbs and paths etc.. you can use the line as a path and loft the shape along it.

Experiment with both methods on a small curve to see what effect works best for your purpose.